# Im trying to iterate through the elements of an array, but also use a different element from that same array. (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, iterator

IM JUST TRYING NEW WAYS TO SOLVE IT
Basicly am trying to iterate through all the elements of an array. But at the same time im on the iteration, i need to use the other two elements of the array. For example, i have an array with lenght [3]. I iterate through the first element [0], and while im in this iteration i want to use element [1] and element [2]. And do the same with the other elemnts. Here is my code (i´been testing thats why its a bit messy).  I need to calculate the hypotenuse with all the elements to find if the triangle is a right one.

```
static void miEjercicio11(){
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double lados[]=new Double[3];
        System.out.println("Ingrese un lado de su triangulo:");
        lados[0] = myObj.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ingrese otro lado de su triangulo:");
        lados[1] = myObj.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ingrese otro lado de su triangulo:");
        lados[2] = myObj.nextDouble();
        int contador=0;
        for(int x=0;x<lados.length;x++){
            double raices[]={Math.pow(lados[contador],2),Math.pow(lados[contador+1],2)};
            double sumaDeRaices = raices[0]+raices[1];
            double hip = Math.sqrt(sumaDeRaices);
            if(lados[contador+2]==hip){
                System.out.println("Es un triangulo rectangulo");
                break;
            }
            else if(contador==2){
                System.out.println("No es un triangulo rectangulo");
                break;
            }
            contador++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think because you have three `double`s exactly and this is inherent in the design (you appear to be calculating with a triangle, three points by definition) I think trying to iterate is a mistake.  Remove the loop, just use the three points by their indexes.  (But you might consider not using an array at all.  `double a, b, c;` would be fine for a triangle.)

Comment: Ive done that. I was just trying to find another way to make it. But im not sure if its possible or even worth it trying. :/